# SQL Error: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option creating composite key

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am trying to create a composite primary key for my table using emp_id and licence_cert_no why is this not working?

```
CREATE TABLE employee_licence_certificate(emp_id NUMBER(4) REFERENCES employee(emp_id)
, licence_cert_code VARCHAR2(6) REFERENCES licence_certificate(licence_cert_code)
, date_earned DATE NOT NULL) 
CONSTRAINT pk_emp_licence PRIMARY KEY(emp_id, licence_cert_code)
```

**Error Message:**

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
CREATE TABLE employee_licence_certificate(emp_id NUMBER(4) REFERENCES employee(emp_id)
, licence_cert_code VARCHAR2(6) REFERENCES licence_certificate(licence_cert_code)
, date_earned DATE NOT NULL) 
CONSTRAINT pk_emp_licence PRIMARY KEY(emp_id, licence_cert_code)
Error at Command Line:3 Column:29
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Answer (score 4):

The `CONSTRAINT` clause needs to go inside the parentheses:

```
CREATE TABLE employee_licence_certificate(
  emp_id NUMBER(4) REFERENCES employee(emp_id)
, licence_cert_code VARCHAR2(6) REFERENCES licence_certificate(licence_cert_code)
, date_earned DATE NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT pk_emp_licence PRIMARY KEY(emp_id, licence_cert_code)
);
```

([reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7002.htm#i2062833))

Comment: or outside, but with `ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT`. And don't forget `;`