# Composite Foreign Key - Possible In Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am trying to create a relation/table in Oracle that is between two many to many tables and therefore the Primary key of this table is a composite key but both keys are foreign.

```
CREATE TABLE employee_licence_certificate(
    emp_id NUMBER(4) REFERENCES employee(emp_id)
    , licence_cert_code VARCHAR2(6) REFERENCES licence_certificate(licence_cert_code)
    , date_earned DATE NOT NULL
    ) 
PRIMARY KEY (emp_id, licence_cert_code))
```

I have tried using the method for composition keys but I seem to get the following error, which is starting to make me wonder is this even possible?

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
CREATE TABLE employee_licence_certificate(emp_id NUMBER(4) REFERENCES employee(emp_id)
, licence_cert_code VARCHAR2(6) REFERENCES licence_certificate(licence_cert_code)
, date_earned DATE NOT NULL) PRIMARY KEY (emp_id, licence_cert_code))
Error at Command Line:3 Column:29
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Error: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option creating composite key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426047/sql-error-ora-00922-missing-or-invalid-option-creating-composite-key)

Comment: yes sorry I forgot I asked that yesterday night/morning I was just up all night working and forgot about that. Forgive me. @JustinCave

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE employee_licence_certificate(
    emp_id NUMBER(4) REFERENCES employee(emp_id)
  , licence_cert_code VARCHAR2(6) REFERENCES licence_certificate(licence_cert_code)
  , date_earned DATE NOT NULL
  ,
PRIMARY KEY (emp_id, licence_cert_code))
```

Comment: yes that worked but I swear it is exactly the same as mine, I think I am overlooking something please could you point this out so I don't make the same mistake in the future and thank you! @chance

Comment: No you have a wrong placed right parentheses, and missed a comma.

Comment: You error was you had a closing bracket `)` between the date column and the primary key, but @chance use a comma `,` which is why it works.

Comment: I seriously can not see that could you please point it out, many thanks @chance

Comment: @Jatinder Singh Now I reformat your SQL, and you can see the difference.

Comment: @Sodved thank you I can not believe I missed that thank you very much I like your example very useful I will sure look into it to further my learning thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

I use a different syntax. I prefer to explicitly name my foreign key constraints so that the error message if/when its violated is more meaningful/tracable. So I would do it something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE employee_licence_certificate
(   emp_id              NUMBER(4)   NOT NULL
,   licence_cert_code   VARCHAR2(6) NOT NULL
,   date_earned         DATE        NOT NULL
,   CONSTRAINT elc_pk PRIMARY KEY (emp_id, licence_cert_code)
,   CONSTRAINT elc_emp_fk FOREIGN KEY (emp_id)
        REFERENCES employee(emp_id)
,   CONSTRAINT elc_lct_fk FOREIGN KEY (licence_cert_code )
        REFERENCES licence_certificate(licence_cert_code)
)
```

Comment: Damn you, I was just trying to post the same answer :)

Answer (score 2):

It sure is possible. You simply need to fix your statement:

```
CREATE TABLE employee_licence_certificate(emp_id NUMBER(4) REFERENCES employee(emp_id)
, licence_cert_code VARCHAR2(6) REFERENCES licence_certificate(licence_cert_code)
, date_earned DATE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (emp_id, licence_cert_code))
```

By the way, it is MUCH easier to spot such errors when you format your statements properly:

```
create table employee_licence_certificate
(
  emp_id number(15) references employee(emp_id),
  licence_cert_code VARCHAR2(6) REFERENCES licence_certificate(licence_cert_code),
  date_earned date not null,
  primary key (emp_id, licence_cert_code)
)
```